# Why can't you pass arguments into setTimeout in a self referencing function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I think there is a better way to do this, and perhaps someone can point out my mistakes.
I am pulsing the box-shadow blur css property by counting up and down, having the function call itself once it is initiated.

For some reason I can't pass the arguments to the setTimeout call that were passed in the first time.

Any ideas on how to more cleanly write this? 
It works, but it would be nice to even generalize it for animating other css properties.

```
var pulseBoxShadowBlurCounter = 0;
var pulseBoxShadowBlurDirection;

$(document).ready(function() { // dom binds

pulseBoxShadowBlur($('#getData-btn'),14,'#fff',100); // start the process

});

function pulseBoxShadowBlur(pulseElement,max,color,delayTime){
var cssInput = '0px 0px '+pulseBoxShadowBlurCounter+'px '+color;
$(pulseElement).css('box-shadow', cssInput);

    if(pulseBoxShadowBlurCounter == max){
        pulseBoxShadowBlurDirection = 1; // backwards
    }

    if(pulseBoxShadowBlurCounter == -5){ // negative num for pause at 0 time
        pulseBoxShadowBlurDirection = 0; // forward
    }

    if(pulseBoxShadowBlurDirection == 0){ 
        pulseBoxShadowBlurCounter++;
    }else{
        pulseBoxShadowBlurCounter--;
    }

setTimeout( "pulseBoxShadowBlur($('#getData-btn'),14,'#fff',100);",delayTime ); // loop
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error?  what is the exact issue?  I would just pass an anonymous function to setTimeout instead

Comment: Actually I'm not sure why that wouldn't work ...

Comment: Oh I see - what you've posted is not the code that **doesn't** work, but the code that **does** work.  That's kind-of not a good idea on Stackoverflow because it's really confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

```
setTimeout(function() { pulseBoxShadowBlur(element, max, color, delayTime); }, delayTime);
```

In general, passing a string version of some JavaScript code as the first argument of  `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` is a bad idea. Pass a function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in a closure, like this:

```
setTimeout( function() {
   pulseBoxShadowBlur($('#getData-btn'),14,'#fff',100);
}),delayTime );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you can use `delay` with `queue` like this:

```
$('#getData-btn').delay(delayTime).queue(function(next) {
  pulseBoxShadowBlur($(this),14,'#fff',100);
  next(); // resume queue
});
```